# Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 - can't get back to Windows

Tags: windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a laptop already running Windows 7. At startup I expected to be able see the option allowing to me to go to either of the two. However I just go straight to Ubuntu.

I did the installation by downloading to a USB and working from there.

I'm not sure where to go from here? How do I manage to get Windows 7 to startup?
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the result of those 2 commands

- fgrep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
- sudo fdisk -l

Comment: Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: How much/what lines from the the first command starting 'fgrep' would you need?

Comment: can you please post the result exactly like in the terminal
or  you can just make screenshot :)

Comment: The screenshots are here - http://www.flickr.com/photos/9998484@N05/10448580595/

Comment: are you sure you didn't  delete the windows partition,  during  the installation of ubuntu ?

try to update the grub with a live CD  !

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't delete it it but.... 
I worked from a USB. Can I update the grub from that?

Comment: are we talking about live USB  ! or a full installation USB ?

Comment: A full installation USB.

Comment: we need a live one :)